# Need help for TAR shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, tar

I am new in the shell scripting. I have written this following script for 2 different input files:

```
#!/bin/sh
last=`ls [JKT-ABC]*.tar | sed s/.tar//g | sort -g | tail -1`
if(($last%1==0))
then
     tar -cf `date '+%W%b%d'`.tar [JKT-ABC]*.tar
fi

last=`ls [JKT-DEF]*.tar | sed s/.tar//g | sort -g | tail -1`
if(($last%1==0))
then
     tar -cf `date '+%W%b%d'`.tar [JKT-DEF]*.tar
fi
```

After executing this script, the output is a single `.tar` file with the name: `xxSep28`. So, the 2 input `.tar` files have become one TAR (`xxSep28`). This is not what I want.

My question is:

- How can I output/use the full name of the `tar` file in the script? (for example: `xx.Sep28.JKT-ABC`)
- Why are the two output files merged into one by this script? How do I keep them separate?

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve?  I mean, what do you want your script to do?

Comment: i want to make output tar files have a name like this xx.Sep28.JKT-ABC and packing tar files into 2 files (because in this script i input 2 different files and after execute the files always become unite).

Comment: I'm a afraid I still don't get it.  The code you show does not take any input and performs the exact same task twice (probably overwriting the just-created tar file again).  That is, if the if-statement were valid.  Could you maybe give an example with “directory before”, “script invocation” and “directory after”?

Comment: Sorry, I can't help you with such sparse information.  Maybe it is just me and somebody else can make more sense out of your question in which case I would like to apologize for asking silly questions.  But if not, you should really make clear in your question what you want to do or you'll have a hard time getting a useful answer.

Comment: cd /backup_files/backup/weekly 
in weekly dir i have these files :
JKT-ABC
JKT-DEF
JKT-GHI
and want to execute these sh script, and i confuse to find script to show up file name completely not only date

Comment: **Never** use `ls` in scripts. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Answer (score 1):

Your question is very hard to understand... your script creates a tar file called

```
<week><month><day>.tar         # 38Sep28.tar today for example
```

and then immediately overwrites it with another tar file with the same name and different contents.

The obvious thing to do is make the two `tar` commands each write to a different file. So I would suggest you change the first `tar` command to:

```
tar -cf "$(date '+%W%b%d')JKT-ABC.tar" something
```

and the second to

```
tar -cf "$(date '+%W%b%d')JKT-DEF.tar" something
```

There is another problem though that I still don't understand, and that is what you mean by

```
[JKT-ABC]*.tar
```

it means files that have names made only of the letters J, K, T through to A (!), B or C followed by `.tar`, so it will match files called:

```
JJ.tar
CBACBACBCCCCCCCC.tar
```

and I don't think that is what you mean, especially since the range `T through to A` is unlikely...